# Slaves in locust are disconnecting automatically

Tags: locust

I am running 10,000 users test in locust using 3 slaves, I am not giving any time out. after all the users are spawned the slaves are disconnected without any error showing, How to avoid this?

Comment: Hi! You'll need to give a lot more details, like your test plan, the parameters you are using, log output etc.

Comment: there are no parameters, I am hitting a simple api. I am hatching 100 users every second

Comment: Please add your log output (slave side and master side)

Comment: You need to specify *a lot* more details if anyone should be able to help you.